# How do I make a fixed range?

Tags: highcharts

I have the [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/elias2012/226ny/)

and I have range of data from 1 to 40

On my chart signed on 1 with function:

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
  // specify an interval for ticks or use max and min to get the interval
  var interval = Math.round((max-min)/4);
  // push the min value at beginning of array
  var dataMin=this.dataMin;
  var dataMax=this.dataMax;          
  var positions = [dataMin];
  var defaultPositions = this.getLinearTickPositions(interval, dataMin, max);
  //push all other values that fall between min and max
  for (var i = 0; i < defaultPositions.length; i++) {
    if (defaultPositions[i] > dataMin && defaultPositions[i] < dataMax) {
      positions.push(defaultPositions[i]);
    }
  }
  // push the max value at the end of the array
  positions.push(dataMax);
  return positions;
}
```

but I want to make a fixed range (1 to 10, 10 to 20, 20 to 30, 30 to 40) - [example](http://regexinfo.ru/my_infa/parse_position/good/chart/1.JPG) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your limits are always going to be the same (1-40) you can probably hard code the tick positions as follows

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
     return [1,10,20,30,40];
}
```

Or if you want your ticks to always be at 10 apart you can do that by specifying the [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickInterval) as `10`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/QPctg/)

Comment: ok, thanks! :) but 40 not singned on chart http://jsfiddle.net/elias2012/226ny/2/

Comment: @I.Zaytsev please go through the documentation, it has most of the things in it. To get 40 on the axis you need to set `showLastLabel:true` example: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/226ny/4/